# Is there a way to make this function run on an incremented number of results?

Tags: javascript

I went through some Cisco tutorials and some help from a friend to make a function that runs some commands based on the results of a device's status.

I'd like to  increment the device's status, then run the function based on X number of results.

I tried creating a variable of 0, then incrementing the results, but I can't figure out how to apply that to the function.

```
xapi.status.on("RoomAnalytics PeoplePresence", checkPeopleCount);

function checkPeopleCount(peeps) {
    if (peeps === 'No') {
        xapi.command("Presentation Stop");
        console.log('Content Stopped');
    }
}
```

Ultimately, instead of running some commands based on one 'No' response, I'd like it to run on 3 or more 'No' responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical way to do this is to capture the count variable in a closure and return a new function that uses that count, which you can then pass to your handler. For demo purposes `b.addEventListener` is analogous to your `xapi.status.on`

```js
let b = document.getElementById('button')
function checkPeopleCount() {
  let count = 0
  return function(peeps) {
    if (count === 3) {
      console.log("hit three: count is:", count)

    } else {
      console.log("count: ", count)
    }
    count++
  }
}
let counter = checkPeopleCount()

b.addEventListener('click', counter)
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

(obviously not tested), but this would translate to something roughly like:

```
function makeCounter() {
    let clicks = 0
    return function(peeps){
        if (clicks === 3) {
            xapi.command("Presentation Stop");
            console.log('Content Stopped');
        } else if(peeps === 'No') {
            clicks++;
        } else {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    }

}
checkPeopleCount = makeCounter()

xapi.status.on("RoomAnalytics PeoplePresence", checkPeopleCount);
```